# C3 Chart not displaying in Bootstrap Modal until window resize

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, c3.js

Hello I'm trying to add a C3 Chart into my Bootstrap Modal, but whenever the chart is generated it will not display in the modal until after I resize my window.

Has anyone run into this issue before, how do I fix it?
Loading the Chart after the Bootstrap Modal has finished sliding down displays the chart... but it would be nice if I can have the chart there as it slide's down.
Here is an example of my code

```
      var chart = c3.generate(
      {
        bindto: '#modal_graph',
        data: {
          columns: [
            ['data1', 30, 200, 500, 100],
            ['data2', 20, 10, 300, 90]
          ],
        },
      });

      $("#alertModal").modal("toggle");
```

Answer (score 4):

http://jsfiddle.net/ot19Lyt8/

use `shown.bs.modal` evetn to set the chart

```
  $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

      var chart = c3.generate({
          data: {
              columns: [
                  ['data1', 100, 200, 150, 300, 200],
                  ['data2', 400, 500, 250, 700, 300], ]
          }
      });

  })
```

Comment: maybe its bad idea to create the chart all time when modal is shown . what about any static one time solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I correct a response of the @dm4web, it's working perfectly:
**Don't forget linked d3.js before c3.js!!!**
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ot19Lyt8/390/)

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

```
var chart = c3.generate({
   bindto: "#chart",
   data: {
      columns: [
           ['data1', 100, 200, 150, 300, 200],
           ['data2', 400, 500, 250, 700, 300],
       ]
   }
   });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack that might give you what you want. Create the chart in a modal that is already showing, then immediately apply the classes to hide it until it is requested.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', 100, 200, 150, 300, 200],
            ['data2', 400, 500, 250, 700, 300], ]
    }
});
$('#myModal').addClass("modal fade");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ot19Lyt8/1/

Answer (score 0):

Better load the c3 or d3 charts one time on page load then use  "resize" on modal show

```
var chart;
function on_page_load_one_time(){

chart = c3.generate({
bindto: "#chart",
data: {
  columns: [
       ['data1', 100, 200, 150, 300, 200],
       ['data2', 400, 500, 250, 700, 300],
   ]
}
});
}
```

and then after modal show

```
$('#d3modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    chart.resize();
});
```